# SQL: How can I add multiple items inside a column?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, blob

Suppose I have a table called users. Inside users there are three columns: username, password and images. In the 'images' column the user should be able to upload images from the program as BLOBs and reaccess them as needed. So there should be multiple image items inside one row in the 'images' column per each user. The program will be in java jdbc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a good time to use a different table. For example, adding a new table `UserImages` with columns of `UserImageID, Username, Image` with a foreign key on the `Username` and primary key on `UserImageID` lets you create a many-to-one mapping of images to users, which is what you're looking for.

Instead, if you put multiple (and of variable length) entries inside a single entry, then that defeats the purpose of database rdbms design. For more information, take a look at the first normal form of database. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: Thank you. I did what you said and added a foreign key to the new table back to the initial table. Can you link me a tutorial on how I would get the username to carry over from the original table to organize the images with? Or do I just do it like I would upload any other data in sql?

Comment: Hm, do you not have a primary key on your Users table? If your primary key is username, then the foreign key should be the username that you want. I'm not too sure what you mean by "carry over" - your entries would be in the new table should be something like row1=`UserImageID=0, Username="something", Image=abc.jpg`, row2=`1, "something", bcd.jpg`, etc...

Comment: yes i have the primary key in the user table too. okay i see now.